# Use of ReflectionTestUtils.setField() in Junit testing

Tags: java, spring, junit

I am new in JUnittesting so i have a question. Can anyone please tell me why we use `ReflectionTestUtils.setField()` in our Junit testing with example.

Comment: Please tell what you are trying to achieve and what have you tried ?

Comment: the [java doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/util/ReflectionTestUtils.html) explains the usage pretty well

Comment: I have seen some examples of junit classes in which uses reflectiontestUtils.setField() in Before annotation but I am not able to understand why it is used and what is the need of it. I just want to know basics. @Mritunjay

Comment: Without looking at that example I can only guess, which is not something I would try.

Comment: You don't need to change system under test in unnatural way. Using reflection in unit tests is contrary of unit testing idea.

Answer (score 31):

As mentioned in the comment, the java docs explain the usage well. But I want to give you also a simple example.

Let's say you have an Entity class with private or protected field access and **no provided setter method**.

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity {

   @Id
   private Long id;

   public Long getId(Long id){
       this.id = id;
   }
}
```

In your test class, you cannot set an `id` of your `entity` because of the missing setter method.

Using `ReflectionTestUtils.setField` you are able to do that for testing purpose:

```
ReflectionTestUtils.setField(myEntity, "id", 1);
```

The Parameters are described:

```
public static void setField(Object targetObject,
                            String name,
                            Object value)
Set the field with the given name on the provided targetObject to the supplied value.
This method delegates to setField(Object, String, Object, Class), supplying null for the type argument.

Parameters:
targetObject - the target object on which to set the field; never null
name - the name of the field to set; never null
value - the value to set
```

But give it a try and read the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/util/ReflectionTestUtils.html).

Answer (score 7):

One more Use Case:

As a best practice we externalised many properties that we want change in application when thwty are subject to change. Such as: URL's , endpoint and many other properties in application properties like below:

```
kf.get.profile.endpoint=/profile
kf.get.clients.endpoint=clients
```

and then these config we can use it in application like below using @Value annotation:

```
  @Value("${kf.get.clients.endpoint}")
  private String clientEndpoint
```

but these values we cannot easily set in unit tests because for encapsulation purpose we should be keep these values as private. therefore whenevver when we write unit test , we get **NullPointerException** because Spring cannot inject @value similarly as @Autowired does. ( at least at the moment , I dont know alternative. ) so to avoid that we can use **ReflectionTestUtils** to inject externalised properties. like below:

```
ReflectionTestUtils.setField(targetObject,"clientEndpoint","lorem");
```

Answer (score 2):

it's very useful when we want to write unit test, such as:

```
class A{
   int getValue();
}

class B{
   A a;
   int caculate(){
       ...
       int v = a.getValue();
       ....
   }
}

class ServiceTest{
   @Test
   public void caculateTest(){
       B serviceB = new B();
       A serviceA = Mockito.mock(A.class);
       Mockito.when(serviceA.getValue()).thenReturn(5);
       ReflectionTestUtils.setField(serviceB, "a", serviceA);
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for above discussions, the below part can also contribute in writing the unit tests by reading the properties from application-test.properties.

```
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.TestPropertySource;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.util.ReflectionTestUtils;

import java.util.List;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
@TestPropertySource("classpath:application-test.properties")
public class FileRetrivalServiceTest {

@Value ("${fs.local.quarantine.directory}")
private String localQuarantineDirectory;

@Value ("${fs.local.quarantine.wrong.directory}")
private String localQuarantineWrongDirectory;

@Value ("${fs.local.quarantine.tmp.directory}")
private String localQuarantineTmpDirectory;

@Value ("${fs.local.keys.file}")
private String localKeyFile;
private FileRetrivalService fileRetrivalService;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    fileRetrivalService = new FileRetrivalServiceImpl();
    ReflectionTestUtils.setField(fileRetrivalService, "keyFile", localKeyFile);
}

@Test
public void shouldRetrieveListOfFilesInQuarantineDirectory() {
    // given
    ReflectionTestUtils.setField(fileRetrivalService, "quarantineDirectory", localQuarantineDirectory);

    // when
    List<IcrFileModel> quarantineFiles = fileRetrivalService.retrieveListOfFilesInQuarantineDirectory();

    // then
    assertNotNull(quarantineFiles);
    assertEquals(quarantineFiles.size(), 4);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`ReflectionTestUtils.setField` is used is various contexts. But the most common scenario is when you have a class and inside that, there are attributes with private access, and you want to test this class.

So a possible solution can be using `ReflectionTestUtils` like in the example below:

```java
public class BBVAFileProviderTest {

    @Mock
    private BBVAFileProvider bbvaFileProvider;

    @Before
    public void setup() throws Exception {
        bbvaFileProvider = new BBVAFileProvider(payoutFileService, bbvaFileAdapter, bbvaCryptographyService, amazonS3Client, providerRequestService, payoutConfirmationService);
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(this.bbvaFileProvider, "bbvaClient", this.bbvaClient);
    }

    // ...

}
```

In this example can you see, that `ReflectionTestUtils.setField` is used to set the value to the private field because it doesn't have a setter method.

Comment: This doesn't add anything that pre-existing answers don't already cover adequately. Better to find questions that need an answer.