# How can I set a parameter which is of type BiFunction using ReflectionTestUtils

Tags: java

Assuming I have a class:

```java
class A {
    private BiFunction<string, string, string> biFuncParam;
}
```

How can change this param using:

```java
ReflectionTestUtils.setField(instance, "biFuncParam", newBiFunc)
```

When I try this it gives me *method not found error* (obviously) as it expects an object param.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use of ReflectionTestUtils.setField() in Junit testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44667573/use-of-reflectiontestutils-setfield-in-junit-testing)

Comment: I tried doing 
`ReflectionTestUtils.setField(instance, "biFuncParam", newBiFunc, BiFunction.class);`

it still gives me an error saying cannot resolve setField in ReflectionTestUtils

Comment: I actually figured out a way around this
Earlier which didnt work and it complained about cannot resolve setField:

`ReflectionTestUtils.setField(instance, "biFuncParam", (x, y) -> x + y)
`
So i took out `(x, y) -> x +y` into a separate variable and passed that variable as param in place of passing the lambda directly and it worked